# Create custom tabular environment

Tags: tables, environments

In the process of creating a beamer template from a PowerPoint template, I am trying to create a tabular environment with colored rows, lines between the rows and specific header and footer styles. Currently I have the layout mixed in an environment that takes care of the alternating rowcolors, but I didn't manage to define the header and footer rows or the style of the separating lines in my environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \rowcolors{1}{red!10}{green!30}
  \arrayrulecolor{white}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{#1}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}{l!{\textcolor{white}{\vrule width 1pt}}c!{\textcolor{white}{\vrule width 1pt}}r}
  \rowcolor{blue}
      & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Standard}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Varianz}} \\ \noalign{{\color{white}\hrule height 2pt}}
    x & x & x \\ \noalign{{\color{white}\hrule height 1pt}}
    x & x & x \\ \noalign{{\color{white}\hrule height 1pt}}
    x & x & x \\ \noalign{{\color{white}\hrule height 2pt}}
  \rowcolor{blue} x & x & x
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

I would like to combine those styles in a way that I can still define the number and alignment of columns, but have the separators fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could come up with until now is this:

```
\newcolumntype{|}{!{\color{white}\vrule width 1pt}}

\newcommand{\ihline}{
 \noalign{{\color{white}\hrule height 1pt}}
}

\newcommand{\iihline}{
  \noalign{{\color{white}\hrule height 2pt}}
}

\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]
{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \rowcolors{1}{blue}{green}
  \arrayrulecolor{white}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \rowcolor{red}}
{\end{tabular}}
```

This allows the user to define their tables almost like they would usually do

```
\begin{mytabular}{l|c|r}
    & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{x}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{x}} \\ \iihline
  x & x & x \\ \ihline
  x & x & x \\ \ihline
  x & x & x \\ \ihline
  x & x & x
\end{mytabular}
```

It would be nice to be able to set the font for the header row like I can set the rowcolor, but this is already much better then the version I had in the question.